# Пример SOAP запроса на Python?

Tags: python, soap

Имеются SOAP запросы такого вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <NS1:GetVersion xmlns:NS1="urn:DCCIntf-IDCC">
      <user></user>         - имя пользователя
      <pass></pass>         - пароль пользователя
    </NS1:GetVersion>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Который каким то образом необходимо отправлять на адрес вида:
http://IP:Port/wsdl

Поделитесь примером как можно реализовать такой запрос посредством Python?

Или ссылкой на какие либо материалы по данному вопросу?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175489/sending-soap-request-using-python-requests

Comment: Да, я примерно так и реализовал, но ответ от сервера непонятный получаю: "Удовлетворительных результатов не найдено"

Comment: По этому мне необходим заведомо рабочий пример запроса на какой либо сервер... Для того что бы можно было проверить, что я не ошибся в коде и сервер действительно не корректно отвечает на мой запрос. Дело в том, что сервер мне не принадлежит и я не уверен в корректности его работы:(

Comment: Разобрался, как с помощью SoapUI, отправить запрос... 
Сервер все таки ответил:) 
Но когда отправляю запрос с помощью Питона, в ответ получаю только список методов, как будто не какого запроса не отправляется, а просто перехожу на страницу "/wsdl". Получается что код не работает:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Блин, получилось все таки:) 
Так я и думал, загвоздка была в том, что администратор сервера дал мне не правильный адрес для отправки запроса:( В итоге по адресу сервера с приставкой /wsdl, получил список поддерживаемых методов, в том числе, там был указан и адрес для запроса.

А вот сама программа для запроса:

```
import requests

endpoint = "здесь адрес для запроса"

body="""здесь запрос"""

body = body.encode('utf-8')
session = requests.session()
session.headers = {"Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"}
session.headers.update({"Content-Length": str(len(body))})
response = session.post(url=endpoint, data=body, verify=False)

print(response.content)
```

Comment: `session.headers.update({"Content-Length": str(len(body))})` -> `session.headers["Content-Length"] = len(body)`. Кст, requests должен сам `"Content-Length"`заполнить

Comment: Не понял, в смысле? Вы намекаете на то, что еще нужно было добавить: "Content-Length="'здесь запрос'" ?

Comment: Нет, я написал что ваш код, который в комментарии привел, можно заменить более простым кодов, а в идеале вообще убрать, т.к. `requests` сам должен добавить в запрос заголовок `Content-Length`

Comment: Все равно не понял, что вы имеете ввиду? В место моего кода, использовать этот "session.headers.update({"Content-Length": str(len(body))}) -> session.headers["Content-Length"] = len(body)" ?

Comment: Ага, я указал строчку кода которую можно упростить, не потеряв ее работоспособность. А после добавил что ее можно не указывать, т.к. requests все-равно ее заполнит